# Как подключить библиотеку к расширению chrome, manifest v3?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, manifest

Необходимо подключить библиотеку SIPml.js в chrome-расширение. Использоваться эта библиотека должна в файле background.js. Использую manifest v3. Во второй версии подключилось вот таким образом:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["SIPml.js", "background.js"]
  }
```

но в манифесте v3, так уже сделать нельзя.
вот манифест v3

```
{
  "name": "__MSG_name__",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "__MSG_description__",
  "default_locale": "ru",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "32": "./icons/phone32.png",
    "64": "./icons/phone64.png",
    "128": "./icons/phone128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://example.local/*",
      "*://example.com/*"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "all_frames": false,
      "js": [
        "content-script.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://example.local/*",
      "*://example.com/*"
  ],
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "matches": [
      "*://example.local/*",
      "*://example.com/*"
    ],
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [ {
    "matches": [ "\u003Call_urls>" ],
    "resources": ["SIPml.js" ]
  } ],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"
  }
}
```

Как подключить библиотеку к расширению в v3 и как использовать ее в background.js? И возможно ли это в третьей версии?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/migrate/to-service-workers?hl=ru